# combine calculation into one sql or pl/sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a single sql or pl/sql to accomplish the following:

```
select value1 from table1;
-----------------------------
99

select value2 from table2;
------------------------------
120
```

I need to find out 99 is what percentage of 120?

Based on the formula `P = X1/X2 * 100` the result will be `82.5%`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Will there always be a single row in both `table1` and `table2`?  If not, how do you know which row from `table1` to compare against which row in `table2`?

Answer (score 0):

It'll work if both tables have a single row (that's what your examples suggest). I used CTE instead of your "real" tables, so query you might be interested in begins at line #7.

```
SQL> with
  2  table1 (value1) as
  3    (select 99 from dual),
  4  table2 (value2) as
  5    (select 120 from dual)
  6  --
  7  select a.value1 / b.value2 * 100 as result
  8  from table1 a cross join table2 b;

    RESULT
----------
      82,5

SQL>
```

---

As you stated that PL/SQL could be an option, consider creating a function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_pct(par_1 in number, par_2 in number)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    return par_1 / par_2 * 100;
  6  exception
  7    when others then
  8      -- in case of e.g. PAR_2 = 0
  9      return null;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.
```

Let's test it:

```
SQL> select ename, sal, comm, f_pct(comm, sal) result
  2  from emp;

ENAME             SAL       COMM     RESULT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
SMITH             800
ALLEN            1600        300      18,75
WARD             1250        500         40
JONES            2975
MARTIN           1250       1400        112
BLAKE            2850
<snip>
```

Comment: To me, the example doesn't suggest two tables, each having exactly one row. What it does suggest is that the OP is a beginner who needs to think again about the question he asked. Perhaps the tables are matched on an id or similar, and they must be joined?